# Criar arquivo automatico PHP

Tags: php, html

Tenho um Painel de Administração, e gostaria que : Toda vez que alguém se cadastrar, seja criado esse Painel automaticamente(todos arquivos).

Estou usando o `fopen();` porém estou na `4737` linha e não nem a metade do Painel, possui algum outro método para eu 'Criar' estes arquivos automaticamente?! [EDIT]

Comment: Leitura fundamental: [ask]. Lembre-se que você sabe o que você quer fazer, mas a gente só tem esses seus 2 parágrafos aí em cima, que não dão a mínima idéia do contexto. Procure ler o link indicado, e depois [edit] a pergunta explicando melhor o que precisa de fato (que arquivos são esses, pq são muitos, que 4737 linhas são essas, fazer isto o que exatamente, etc). Estamos aqui para ajudar, mas para isso precisamos entender qual é a situação.

Comment: :) Obrigado pela indicação amigo! fiz um edit se não entender ainda me avise, acho que ficou claro agora.. Só não entendi o voto negativo. Isso desproporciona a pergunta e deixei de uma forma objetiva que quero criar arquivos automaticamente sem usar o metedo de **fopen**

Comment: Diria que deu um passinho, mas ainda não dá pra saber qual é o critério de criação. Se quiser aplicar um "template" de site a um cliente novo, seria só copiar uma pasta inteira com os modelos, sem nada de fopen. Crie um diretórtio "/modelo_site/" com todos os arquivos, e ao criar o novo usuário copie todo o conteúdo para "/pasta_do_usuário/" e gere com fopen() apenas os arquivos de configuração, que tiverem senhas etc.

Comment: Poderia ter um arquivo só compactado (.zip) com todos os arquivos essenciais desse "painel admin", então bastaria apenas extrair tudo a cada novo cadastro.

Comment: Pensei nesta possibilidade @DanielOmine , más teria como eu fazer isto de forma automatica? **Ex** extrair o .zip automatico ?

Comment: Sim... As funções zip do PHP http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: @Bacco , entendi o conceito sou novo em programação , como que eu copiaria todos esses arquivos ?! não possui senha pois o propio painel vem com a tela de login

Comment: tem um código pronto aqui que vai criando os diretórios e copiando todos os arquivos http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050909/916193

Answer (score 6):

Uma solução seria criar uma pasta modelo, com tudo o que precisa, e copiar para a pasta do novo usuário.

Veja um código pronto, [tirado do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2050909/916193)

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
?>
```

### Se preferir extrair de um .zip:

Exemplo do site do PHP:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: Irei tentar o **zip** coloco ele na raiz do código ?!

Comment: no open você indica o caminho correto, no extractTo() o destino. Mas eu acho melhor a opção sem zip, dá menos manutenção se for trocar um arquivo ou outro em novas versões. O Zip é bom pra economizar um pouco de espaço, mas é mais lento, consome mais cpu (mas só na hora que usar) e é ruim de manter. De qq forma, se tiver pouco espaço em disco o jeito é o zip. em outros casos, arquivo.

Comment: Tudo bem vou fazer os testes ! Obrigado :D

Comment: Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/ciclumcom/public_html/demo/cadastro/teste/index.php on line 4
ok

Comment: @LucasBicalleto tanto no caso do zip quanto dos arquivos copiados, você precisa acertar as permissões de pasta do servidor. Deve ter alguma pergunta sobre isso no site, mas se não achar soluçao, faça uma separada deste problema específico (pq ai ja foge da pergunta atual). Isso depende do sistema operacional usado. Precisa autorizar o usuário do webserver (apache, por exemplo) a escrever na pasta.

Comment: Obrigado :D vou dar uma olhada

Comment: agora esta dando > falied.

Código : `<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('/public_html/teste_lucas/teste.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/public_html/teste_lucas/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>`

Comment: problema no "open"; veja se o caminho está correto, e se usou compressão padrão (sem ser o modo mais avançado do winzip novo, que é compativel só com ele mesmo).

Answer (score 2):

## Usando a library Zip do PHP

```
function UnzipFile($file_path, $extract_path)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($file_path);
    if ($res === true) {
        $zip->extractTo($extract_path);
        $zip->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

UnzipFile(
    'c:/caminho/completo/do/arquivo.zip',
    'c:/caminho/completo/do/diretorio/onde/quer/extrair/'
);
```

Com algo simples assim poderia resolver.

Bastaria ter um arquivo zip contendo todos os arquivos e pastas do sistema de painel administrativo.

Quando um cliente se cadastrar, descompacte o arquivo para a pasta dessse cliente. Após isso, logicamente, pressuponho que deve ter de alterar alguns arquivos para customizar a instalação para o cliente.

Aí nesse ponto pode usar um `fopen()`, `file_put_contents()` ou outros meios mais amigáveis com interface para um usuário leigo poder fzer as setagens iniciais.

## Usando exec()

Alternativamente, pode optar pela command line.

```
exec('unzip c:/caminho/completo/do/arquivo.zip c:/caminho/completo/do/diretorio/onde/quer/extrair/');
```

Em ambiente Linux normalmente unzip está disponível.

Para ambiente Windows pode usar algum programa específico como 7zip, winrar, ou até o jar do JAVA.

Pela command line é ainda muito mais rápido pois utiliza os recursos do Sistema Operacional.

<sub>obs: O método copiando os arquivos recursivamente é muito mais demorado e ainda corre risco de algo ficar sem copiar. Mas não quer dizer que seja errado e que sempre vai ocorrer falha.</sub>